# Position thumb at the bottom of seekbar android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am trying to make the seekbar below

[image]

appear like this

[image]

i use the following xml attribute with minheight and maxheight but the thumb is not moving to bottom.

The minHeight and maxHeight only affect the seekbar. How can i achieved desired result i.e. thumb at seekbar bottom.

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar_duree"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight_dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/eight_dp"
            android:background="@color/fulll_transparent"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="48500"
            android:maxHeight="60dip"
            android:minHeight="60dip"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/twenty_sp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/nine_patch"

            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
            />
```

:**UPDATE: THIS IS MY THUMB. HOW CAN I PUT IT BELOW THE PROGRESS**

[image]

Comment: create your thumb drawable with extra transparent pixel top

Comment: @Dimitri have you got the solution

Answer (score 1):

I use xml-thumb like this with seek_thumb.9.png wich has the same physical size like min/maxHeight value defined on seekbarlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:constantSize="false">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_pressed_60" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_pressed_60" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_60" /> 
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

seekbar-layout also referencing xml-seekbar

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:max="30"
    android:maxHeight="60dp"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:progress="15"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar"
    android:secondaryProgress="0"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb"
    android:thumbOffset="0dp" />
```

seekbar.xml using *.9.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+android:id/background">
        <nine-patch
            android:dither="true"
            android:src="@drawable/seekbar_back_60" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress">
        <clip 
            android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
            <nine-patch
                android:dither="true"
                android:src="@drawable/seekbar_front_60" />
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```